# jquery find the longest height dynamically to set height to all siblings in div

Tags: jquery, css

I am currently trying to figure out how to set the height of all sibling `p` elements in a div by finding the height of the longest `p` element in that div dynamically without setting the maximum height, got the code from [here](http://www.queness.com/post/126/useful-and-handy-jquery-tips-and-tricks)

I would like to set the height dynamically to the longest `p` dynamically as I don't know the height of the longest `p`

here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setHeight('.col');
});



//global variable, this will store the highest height value
var maxHeight = 100;

function setHeight(col) {
    //Get all the element with class = col
    col = $(col);

    //Loop all the col
    col.each(function() {       

        //Store the highest value
        if($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();;
        }
    });

    //Set the height
    col.height(maxHeight);
 }
```

if someone knows how to do this that would be great

I have a raw javascript solution below but it has to be jquery

```
function parseRightTabs() {
    var height = 20;
    var ht = 0;
    for(var i=1; i<5; i++) {
        ht = Od('rTest'+i).offsetHeight;
        if(ht>height) height = ht;
        if(i>1)Od('rTest'+i).style.display='none';
    }
    if(height < 50) height = 112;
    Od('rTests').style.height = height + 'px';
    Od('rtShow2').style.display = Od('rtShow3').style.display=Od('rtShow4').style.display = 'none'; 
}
```

Hope someone can help

[here](http://satbulsara.com/NSJ-local/eqs1.htm) is the link, if you click on testimonials in the right hand section and click 1, 2 or 3

here is the js fiddle

http://jsbin.com/owiju5/2/edit

Comment: "I have a raw javascript solution below but it has to be jquery" Did you mean this the other way around? jquery IS javascript...

Comment: @josh I've heard that a lot lately, beginners want their JavaScript to be coded jQuery-like.  It's easier for them to understand and provides an entry way into learning native JavaScript methods as they progress...

Comment: i know jquery is javascript but jquery seems more fluid to learn for me coming from a design background

Answer (score 7):

Try this out  --

```
var $paragraphs = $('div p');

var heights = $paragraphs.map(function() {
   return $(this).height();
});

var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(this, heights);

$paragraphs.height(maxHeight);
```

Comment: this almost works, it however adds the buttons halfway up the div but it is consistent so may need a tweek

Comment: //your context (the div you want to check)
   var div = $('.rtTestimonials').get(0),
       heights = [];

   $('.col', div).each(function() {
      heights.push($(this).height());
   });

   var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(this, heights);

   $('.col', div).height(maxHeight);

Comment: @sat Could you start a jsfiddle with the HTML and JS?  I don't mind tweaking it for you to get it right..

Comment: I have a js bin below of it for you. check it out. Thanks

Comment: also I have a font size switcher so it needs to consider this when adjusting the geight.

Comment: @sat I don't see any element containing .rtTestimonials or .col.  And that's a whole lot of HTML and JS.  Check this fiddle for a live working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/7NmBb/  (I changed my code a bit, see above)

Comment: @John Sorry it wasn't compiling all my code here it is http://jsbin.com/ozasu5/5/edit

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin to do that: [Equal Column Heights](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/equal-height-columns)

However in principle your code should do something like this:

```
$elems = $('.my_columns');
var max_height = 0;
$elems.each(function(idx, elem) {
  max_height = Math.max(max_height, $(elem).height());
});
$elems.height(max_height);
```

Comment: It worked with me, but you need to change the colon to be semicolon after each function

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin for setting the height of columns that would make this very easy.

http://brenelz.com/blog/jquery-custom-plug-in-equal-height-columns/

Comment: thanks, i would like to do it without a plugin but if all else fails

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to loop twice. Once to get the highest value and then again and set all the heights to that value.

So something like

```
...

$(".col").each(function() {       

        //Store the highest value
        if($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();;
        }
    });

$(".col").each(function() {       
        $(this).height(maxHeight);
    });

...
```

Comment: .height() automatically iterates over each matched element.

Comment: Than you for the info... Now I have learn't something new today ;)... Is this a standard behavior in most of JQuery or is this function the odd-one-out?

Comment: It's pretty standard, most of the jQuery methods act on the entire collection rather than just a single node.  I'd assume it always does unless the API documentation says so otherwise.  Glad you learned something new :p

Comment: Now I have a few each loops I can get rid of :)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple code

```
var heights = $("element").map(function ()
{
return $(this).height();
}).get(),

MaxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
```

or

```
var highest = null;
 var hi = 0;
$(".testdiv").each(function(){
var h = $(this).height();
 if(h > hi){
 hi = h;
 highest = $(this);  
 }    
});

highest.css("background-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend jQuery to have a `matchHeight()` method. Note these steps:

1. We must call this only after `$(window).load()` is finished because otherwise the maximum height readings will be wrong.
2. Then, the `overflow:hidden` causes our column elements to snap their height to their contents, but only works if their width is set, and most floating column widths are usually set as a general good practice. This is important to do or otherwise your `$(this).height()` reading will be `0` in some cases.
3. Then, when we finally get to the last column, we use the `Math.max.apply()` trick to find the largest column height. However, that trick only works if we have our selector, and the `o` variable goes to a single column elements, not all the column elements. So, we utilize the `selector` property to get that.
4. Then, again, we have to use the `selector` property in order to grab all the siblings and set their height. Note that I tried this with `o.siblings()` instead of `$(o.selector)`, but that failed to work.

```js
(function($) {
$.fn.extend({
  matchHeight: function() {
    var o = $(this);
    o.css('overflow','hidden');
    if (o.is(':last-child')) {
      var nMaxH = Math.max.apply(null,$(o.selector).map(function(){return $(this).height();}).get());
      $(o.selector).height(nMaxH);
    }
  }
});
})(jQuery);

$(window).load(function(){
  // The .row .col below is DIV P in your case, where DIV = .row and P = .col
  $('.row .col').matchHeight();
});
```